# Node.js - how to use one connection with socket.io for several rooms

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat

I need to do a chat, therefore I guess to using node + socket.io. Except that, one person may be on several room in same time. Although we can use io.of('/room1')...
This forces, browser side, to make several connections to several rooms.

Have you got a best suggestion or idea ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of having a "default" room, which will be helpful to maintain presence i.e status of the user whether he is online or offline. This will contain a big list of all users who are online in your application

For each chat that happens between users, better to have dynamic rooms created for each conversation.

Comment: Yes, but that forcing to create several connection browser-slide (io.connect('roomName') ).  Therefore, if a user is connected to 20 rooms, there will are 20 differents connections, no ? Then, I don't think that to know if a user is connected but I like your idea => simple